# Aligning arrows horizontally to an image column

Tags: html, css

Below is my div structure. I've got 2 arraow set on the top and at the bottom.

My question is how do I make the 2 arrows centered and slightly towards the column of images?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b899145q/1/)

I tried this but no luck

```
.arrows{
    border: 3px solid lime;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div class="row">
      <img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows" height="128" width="128" />
    <div id="itemWrapper">
      <div id="items">
          <div class="content">
              <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/p1puE+" class = "thumb" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <img src="http://img42.com/h1DoP+" class="arrows" height="128" width="128" />
  </div>            
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you were on a right track with `display-inline` and `text-align:center`

You just needed to set the align property on the parent element so that any inline or display-inline HTML element inside that parent element would be centered.

```
#Wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
    text-align:center;
    width:300px;
}

.arrows{
    border: 3px solid lime;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

You could also use negative margins on `#itemWrapper` to offset the arrows up and down.

```
#itemWrapper{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    margin-top:-15px;
    margin-bottom:-15px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/slavenko/b899145q/11/)

Answer (score 2):

**Centering the arrows**

Enclose the arrows in `div` tags. Set the width of the `div`s to be the same width as the images. Then, use `text-align: center` in your css, for the div.

```
<div class="arrow-wrapper">
    <img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows" height="128" width="128" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.arrow-wrapper{
    width: 200;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Making them closer**

In order to get them closer to the image, give each arrow its own class:

```
<img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows top" height="128" width="128" />
<img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows bottom" height="128" width="128" />
```

And then put css:

```
.top{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
.bottom{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Slavenco's answer and to wrap this up entirely, I would suggest adding an "arrow-top" class, and "arrow-bottom" class, and adjust the margin to achieve the overlapping effect you are looking for.  You may need to adjust the z-index to make the arrows appear on top.

I wrapped each image like so:

```
<div class="arrow arrow-top">
  <img src="http://img42.com/p2OH4+" class="arrows" height="128" width="128" />
</div>
```

(Of course, the bottom arrow is arrow-bottom instead of arrow top)
and the CSS is as follows:

```
.arrow { width: 100%; text-align:center; }
.arrow-top{ margin-bottom: -10px; }
.arrow-bottom{ margin-top: -10px; }
```

You can obviously adjust the margins until you get the absolute desired overlap you're looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/b899145q/12/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use position: relative; for class="row" and position: absolute; for class="arrows" to get the overlap you want. Take them out of document flow. To just get them to just center without overlap, move the text-align: center; to the containing element.